# VB.NET - Multiple user-input integers to arraylist

Tags: vb.net, variables, user-input, average

I'm new to programming... I'm trying to code a very basic program so that 10 integers can be input by a user, and then averaged. I've considered using an ArrayList to store all the data, but once I use "Input" once I can't use it again.

What I'm supposed to do is take a basic averaging program like this:

```
Dim A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J As Integer
A = 10
B = 6
C = 17
...
...
...
J = 15
Dim K As Double
K = A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J
K /= 10
Console.WriteLine(K)
Console.ReadKey()
```

...and make it so that the user can input all of the variables.

Hopefully this problem is clear enough... anybody know what I can do?

Comment: You should learn about loops (for, while) to repeat a block of code more than one time and a simple array is more than enough to start with

Comment: Forget about `ArrayList`, and use `List(Of Double)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included below and example with comments. Hopefull you will learn from the statements and understand how to loop with `Do/Loop` or `For` and how to use `List(Of )` to store a variable amount of data.

```
Sub Main()
    ' Initialize variable for text input, and numeric value
    Dim input As String, x As Double
    ' Initialize empty array of numbers
    Dim array = New List(Of Double)()
    Do
        Console.Write("Enter a number or press [Enter] to Finish :")
        ' Read a number (as text)
        input = Console.ReadLine()
        ' Check if input is a number
        If (Double.TryParse(input, x)) Then
            ' If it is a number add it to list
            array.Add(x)
        ElseIf x.Length>0
            ' If not then display a message
            Console.WriteLine("** Input Not Numeric **")
        End If
        ' Continue until user presses enter
    Loop Until input.Length = 0
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Numbers Entered", array.Count)
    ' Calculate average from values
    Dim average As Double = 0
    For index As Integer = 1 To array.Count
        average += array(index - 1)
    Next
    average /= array.Count
    ' Display results and wait for enter
    Console.WriteLine("The Average Is {0}", average)
    Console.Write("Press [Enter] to End")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Calculating average can be even more simple: `array.Average()`. Otherwise +1. I was going to write a similar answer.

Comment: Yes, but in the interest of learning it is important to show the internals. In real code, of course `.Average()` should be used, which when examined produces the same code.

Comment: I added a `ElseIf` condition when the user pressed enter so that it does not display the `Not Numeric` message.

Comment: By this logic, OP needs to start with Assembly language. No offense, but I think new programmers need to learn primitives as high as they can get. We learnt a dozen different ways of sorting at university, how many am I using now? Correct, exactly 0. :)

Comment: Yes, but you learned to do things in a loop. The averaging or summing may be builtin, but most of the time there are other specific operations that you do because of your experience with averaging in a loop.

Comment: Cmon, it's good to know higher level primitives, available in VB.NET, such as LINQ. If you do, 90% of the loops are no longer necessary. And that can save you a lot of time. Back in the old days everything was loops, well GOTOs actually. Not anymore! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I've already learned about Do/Loop/For but I didn't think to use that in this situation... Thanks a million!!

Comment: @Neolisk what I intentended to show was the `0` based indexing of arrays and how `array(index-1)` must be used with `VB.NET` if the for loop counter starts from 1. All this would have been lost with the `.Average()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would do things in steps. First your way.

```
    Dim a, b, c, d As Integer

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    a = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    b = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    c = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    d = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

    Console.WriteLine("The average is: " & ((a + b + c + d) / 4))
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Then you convert the code to use a list

```
    Dim v As New List(Of Integer)

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    v.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    v.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    v.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))

    Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
    v.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))

    Console.WriteLine("The average is: " & ((v(0) + v(1) + v(2) + v(3)) / 4))
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Now that you are using a list, you can easely use a loop to remove duplicate code.

```
    Dim v As New List(Of Integer)

    Do While v.Count < 4
        Console.Write("Type an integer: ")
        v.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
    Loop

    Console.WriteLine("The average is: " & ((v(0) + v(1) + v(2) + v(3)) / 4))
    Console.ReadLine()
```

After that you add error validation and use the built-in Average function.

```
    Dim tempVal As Integer
    Dim v As New List(Of Integer)

    Do While v.Count < 4
        Console.Write("Type an integer: ")

        If Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), tempVal) Then
            v.Add(tempVal)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer")
        End If
    Loop

    Console.WriteLine("The average is: " & v.Average())
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: I would add another step of putting the input and calculations into functions so they could be re-used again.

Comment: Wow. This method is big and beautiful...but I think the looping method is more efficient... and easier to type out. :P